# Loop Duplicating Issue

Tags: php

I am trying to make a alphabetical glossary by taking the first charecter of the results and makes a header out of it then returns the full title of the result under it. The problem im having is that when my function calls the results from 1 - Z everything from A - Z duplicates itself where the results from 1 - 9 only display once.

This is the function ive created.

```
function business_listings($states){

    $dbquery = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT CityName FROM {zipcodes} WHERE StateName = '".ucfirst(arg(2))."' ORDER BY CityName ASC");

    $cityname = '';

    $cityname = '<nav id="alphabetize">';

    foreach (range('a', 'z') as $char) {
      $cityname .= '<a href="#sort-'.$char.'">'.ucfirst($char).'</a>';
    }

    $cityname = '</nav>';

    $curr_letter = '';
    $cityname = '<div class="alpha_wrapper">'; 

    foreach ($dbquery as $dbrow) {

    $title_array = explode(' ', $dbrow->CityName);
    $this_letter = substr($title_array[0], 0, 1);

    //Here is where the problem starts to occur
    if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {

        if (!empty($curr_letter)) {
            $cityname .= '<div class="clear"></div></div><div class="alpha_wrapper">';
        }

        $curr_letter .= $this_letter; 
        $cityname .= '<div id="sort-'.strtolower($this_letter).'" class="alpha_title">';
        $cityname .= $this_letter;
        $cityname .= '</div>';
    }//end of if statement where problem is

        $cityname .='<div class="cityname">';
        $cityname .= l($dbrow->CityName, $base_url.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/'.strtolower(urlencode($dbrow->CityName)));
        $cityname .= '</div>';
    }

    return $cityname;
}
```

For example the loop goes something like this.

```
<div headerdiv>1</div>
10 palms
100 palms
1000 palms

<div headerdiv>2</div>
20 palms
200 palms
2000 palms


<div headerdiv>a</div>
apple 1
<div headerdiv>a</div>
apple 2
<div headerdiv>a</div>
apple 3
<div headerdiv>a</div>
apple 4
```

and this continues all the way until Z
the header div should only give one result and apples 1 2 3 and 4 should be under it.

Ive also attached a screenshot if my example wasnt more descriptive.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concatenate `$this_letter` to `$curr_letter`, the successive values of `$curr_letter` will be `1`, `12`, `12A`, `12AB`, `12ABC` and so on. As a result, `$this_letter != $curr_letter` will evaluate to `true` in every iteration of your `foreach` loop. The line in your code which is responsible for such untoward behaviour is this:

```
$curr_letter .= $this_letter;    // concatenate
```

You should change the line to:

```
$curr_letter = $this_letter;    // do not concatenate
```